# Interesting ways to solve $\int \frac{dx}{(z^2 + x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$

Tags: integration

This integral:
$$\int \frac{dx}{(z^2 + x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$
comes up a lot. My only method of solving this using the substitution $x=z\tan(\theta)$. It works fine but I was wondering if there was any other clever ways of solving this integral or any very similar integral?

#### Epilogue

$$\int \frac{dx}{(z^2 + x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{x}{z^2\sqrt{(z^2 + x^2)}} + x_0$$

Comment: Shouldn't it be: $$\int \frac{dz}{(z^2 + x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{z}{x^2\sqrt{(z^2 + x^2)}} + C$$ (it's not about the letter for the constant, it's about $z$ in the numerator and $x^2$ in the denominator

Comment: your own answer seems wrong

Comment: srry, fixed it. I meant dx.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the OP's original variable of integration $z$.

$$z=xt$$

$$\int \frac{dz}{(z^2 + x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{1}{x^2} \int \frac{dt}{(1 + t^2)^\frac{3}{2}}$$

$$1+t^2=s^2, \qquad t=\sqrt{s^2-1}, \qquad dt=\frac{sds}{\sqrt{s^2-1}}$$

$$\int \frac{dt}{(1 + t^2)^\frac{3}{2}}=\int \frac{ds}{s^2\sqrt{s^2-1}}$$

$$s=\frac{1}{y}, \qquad ds=-\frac{dy}{y^2}$$

$$\int \frac{ds}{s^2\sqrt{s^2-1}}=-\int \frac{ydy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}$$

I think it's absolutely obvious that:

$$-\int \frac{ydy}{\sqrt{1-y^2}}=\sqrt{1-y^2}$$

Now getting back to our original variables:

$$y=\frac{1}{s}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+t^2}}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}$$

$$1-y^2=1-\frac{x^2}{x^2+z^2}=\frac{z^2}{x^2+z^2}$$

$$\sqrt{1-y^2}=\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}$$

Finally:

$$\int \frac{dz}{(z^2 + x^2)^\frac{3}{2}}=\frac{1}{x^2} \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}}$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way.

Let
$$x = \frac{1}{u}, \quad dx= -\frac{1}{u^2} \, du.$$
So the integral becomes
$$\int \frac{dx}{(z^2 + x^2)^{3/2}} = - \int \frac{u}{(z^2 u^2 + 1)^{3/2}} \, du.$$

Now let
$$t = z^2 u^2 + 1, \quad u \, du = \frac{dt}{2z^2}.$$
Thus
$$\int \frac{dx}{(z^2 + x^2)^{3/2}} = -\frac{1}{2z^2} \int t^{-3/2} \, dt = \frac{1}{z^2 \sqrt{t}} + C = \frac{1}{z^2 \sqrt{z^2 u^2 + 1}} + C,$$
or
$$\int \frac{dx}{(z^2 + x^2)^{3/2}} = \frac{x}{z^2 \sqrt{z^2 + x^2}} + C.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint...try $z=x\sinh\theta$ instead

Comment: Why the downvote? Are hints not allowed?

Comment: @Isham thanks...!

Comment: yw david we don't use them that much but they are really usefull sometimes

Comment: @Isham I totally agree - much slicker than trig in many cases...